# Code works in PyCharm, but return syntaxerror when i call it by terminal

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, ubuntu-18.04

There is a function:

```
def change_BG_lin (path):
os.system(f"gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri {path}")
```

In PyCharm all works properly, but when i call it in terminal it returns this:

```
 os.system(f"gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri {path}")
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
                                                                         ^
```

Comment: you might be using different version of python in terminal - type just python - it most probably is not 3.6 - so f-string is not valid syntax

Comment: I forgot that in Ubuntu string "python" call python2, instead of python3. My fault, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ubuntu string "python" call to python2, which doesn`t have "f string".